# Can't subclass PFQueryTableViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform

I'm writing an iOS App using Parse.com to interact with a server.

I've downloaded and installed the SKD, added all frameworks correctly and everything works fine until it comes to the `PFQueryTableViewController`. It doesn't appear in the drop down list when I'm creating a new class and I can't create one programmatically because Xcode just doesn't know it. 
Same with a `PFImageView`, is this somehow related?

The SKD should be up to date since I updated it yesterday including the local datastore.

Am I missing here something?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

For anyone using swift having this issue. In your bridging header file make sure you have the following:

```
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import <Bolts/Bolts.h>
#import <ParseUI/ParseUI.h>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities:

1. You do not have the Frameworks compiling properly. Make sure the Frameworks are properly installed by following the instructions here: https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/ios/native/existing
2. The Xcode UI is not seeing the class properly to add it for subclassing - not a big deal. Get around it by starting the creation of a new class, then when you get to the naming page, simply start typing in the 'Subclass of:' box the name `PFQueryTableViewController` and it should autocomplete, as seen in this screenshot:

[image: PFTableViewContoller Suclassing]

### UPDATE:

You may also want to check your 'Link Binary with Libraries' under 'Build Settings'. Be sure that the Parse.framework and Bolts.framework files are listed.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

That's what makes me wonder. I just downloaded and imported the framework again, followed all steps and nothing changed. Xcode only autocompletes ’PFQuery’ but not ’PFQueryTableViewController’. Any other idea what could be wrong?

Comment: To your update: Checked that already, everything is imported correctly.

Comment: Just found a solution! I imported the <ParseUI/ParseUI.h> manually in a .h file and now Xcode knows and autocompletes all classes of the framework.

Comment: Above worked comment worked for me. I imported <ParseUI/ParseUI.h> into my bridging header file.